# How to use the value from a decoded struct that has an enum type value with custom initializers?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

I have an API response that returns a JSON field with inconsistent types. Hence, I went to https://www.quicktype.io for some help and found a model.

Here is the model part where I have an issue:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let id: ID?
}

enum ID: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ID.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ID"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

I have a fully decoded response and when I try to print the value, I get something like:

```
Optional(MyApp.ID.integer(27681250))
```

OR

```
Optional(MyApp.ID.string(27681250))
```

I am doing so by:

```
print(modelData?.id)
```

I want to access the exact value I get but I am unable to do so.
I have tried casting it into other types but it is not helping.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to access it, as a string or an integer or do you just want to access the id value itself? Try to avoid naming your custom type to the same as built in types. Both `Data` and `ID` are already used in swift (Foundation framework).

Comment: I just named it like that here, not in my code. I have edited the name back to something else. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok, good. When you get the id as a string is that string always made up of numbers? If so you could simplify your solution.

Comment: I hope that was the thing. The API I am using gives back either only numbers as `Int` or `String` or sometimes a `String` with alphanumeric values. If I get a string back I need to check if it is numbers only or not which I have handled already.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that if it was numbers only I would have made `id` in MyModel to be of type Int and handle the conversion in `init(from:) there and skipped having this extra enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different ways you could do this. All of them are explained in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book) book in the [Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) section.

Here is just one of the ways...

```swift
func example(id: ID) {
    switch id {
    case let .integer(value):
        <#code#>
    case let .string(value):
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. I was stuck at this thing for such a long time. Will read the docs as soon as I get some time. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: BTW. If it were me, I would convert all the Int ids into strings so all ID types would just be Strings...